# javascript store variable in object for use in function

Tags: javascript, object

2nd version of question (first below)

I am web-scraping with permission using Cheerio. Each store website has a different traversal path for its information. I have an array of objects containing store website information. With help from a response below I am using an arrow function for the productTitle key, but it is returning blank.

```
const sellerArray = [
    {   
        sellerUrl: 'https://www.thebeststoreever.com',
        sellerName: 'The Best Store Ever',
        productTitleFn: ($) => $(this).find('h3').text().trim()       
    }
];

axios(sellerArray[0].sellerUrl)
    .then(response => {
        const html = response.data;
        const $ = cheerio.load(html);
        const productTable = $('.plusplus');
        productTable.each(function () {
            const id=uuid();
            const seller = sellerArray[0].sellerName;
            const productTitle = $(this).find('h3').text().trim();
            console.log(productTitle); //returns "The Greatest Product Ever"
            const productTitleFn = sellerArray[0].productTitleFn($);           
            console.log(productTitleFn); //returns blank
        });       
    })
    .catch(console.error);
```

---

First version of question:
I am web-scraping with permission using Cheerio. Each store website has a different traversal path for its information. I have an array of objects containing store website information. I would like to map this array to a function using variables that are valid inside the function but not inside the object. If I code it like below, I get the error 'html is not defined'. If I put quotes around the 'productTitle' value, of course it just passes a string. How should I approach this?

```
const sellerArray = [
    {   
        sellerUrl: 'https://beststoreever.com'
        sellerName: 'Best Store Ever',
        producTitleTraversalPath: html(this).find('h3').text().trim(),
    },
    {   
        sellerUrl: 'https://2ndbeststoreever.com',
        sellerName: '2nd Best Store Ever',
        producTitleTraversalPath: html(this).find('.myProduct').children[0].text().trim(),
    }
]

function parseStoreInfo(seller, data) {
    const html = cheerio.load(data);
    const products = html('.sellerProductsTableName');

    products.map(item => {
        const id=uuid();
        const sellerName = seller.sellerName;
        const productTitle = seller.productTitleTraversalPath;

        //push to myProductArray for future use
    });
}

sellerArray.map(seller => axios(seller.sellerUrl)
    .then(response => {
        parseStoreInfo(seller, response.data);      
    })
    .catch(console.error));
```

Comment: Yes I renamed to try to be clearer, but missed that correction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was a "this" problem:

Got it! I changed the function inside the object to (do not use 'this' in this line of code):

```
productTitleFn: ($, item) => $(item).find('h3').text().trim()
```

and I changed the function call to:

```
const productTitleFn = sellerArray[0].productTitleFn($, this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try defining the "Extracting the Title" part as a **`function`** inside the array, something like this:

```
productTitleTraversalFn: function(obj) { return obj.find('h3').text().trim(); }
```

Or using arrow function notation:

```
productTitleTraversalFn: obj => obj.find('h3').text().trim();
```

You can then call that function when the object has loaded, along the lines of

```
const productTitle = productTitleTraversalFn($(this));
```

Comment: Thank you Peter, I tried the arrow function, but it is returning blank. See revised code above. I think it's close, but not quite there.

Comment: I made a change, you should probably pass `$(this)` into the function, and not `$`. And change the function to use the thing that you pass in. I'm assuming that `$` stands for jQuery, is it that? It looks like it an awful lot, and if so then that is the way to use it.

Comment: Actually "$" is the Cheerio wrapper identifier. I tried to change it to a more descriptive name, but I got an error, so "$" it is. I also tried to pass in $(this) as you suggested, but again got an error. Things are working with ($, this) so I thank you very much for pointing me in the right direction with the arrow function suggestion.